# I need a break after every coin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, break

How can i make a break after every coin. I need all coins as options.
Now i get all in one line.

```
<option value="Auswahl">
  <% @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).select do |id, coin| %>
  <%= coin['name'].split(";") %> <br /> <p />
 <% end %>
</option>
```

[image: MY Output here:]

```
  <select  id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
   <% @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).each do |id, coin| %>
        <% coin['name'].split(";").each do |i| %>
        <option value = "#{i}"> <%= i %>  </option>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </select>
```

[image: Newlist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code sample:

```
<% result = @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).split(';') %>    
<select>
    <% result.each do |i| %>
       <option value="#{i}"><%= i %></option> 
    <% end %>
</select>
```

Or in general you should loop through this like:

```
<select>
     <% @jsonData.fetch('data', {}).each do |id, coin| %>
        <% coin['name'].split(";").each do |i| %>
        <option value = "#{i}"> <%= i %>  </option>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
</select>
```

and here you should open and close  tag with value and text like sample above

Comment: Hi Nezir, thank you it help me much. :) now i can use some coins but not all... there are 2000 and it only shows 20. See my code at the bottom

Comment: You need to check  @jsonData.fetch('data', {}) how many  names it returns?  I think for this request it is set to return only 20 items